# Error running .exe file in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to make my script run this file:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779

before/after (doesn't matter) I install my application.

This is my script:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

; Flags: skipifsilent

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{AEDD3A70-5044-452B-B78D-9CCE4E130654}
AppName=Pong
AppVersion=2.0
;AppVerName=Pong 2.0
AppPublisher=Roymunson_Studios
AppPublisherURL=http://www.example.com/
AppSupportURL=http://www.example.com/
AppUpdatesURL=http://www.example.com/
DefaultDirName={pf}\Pong
DefaultGroupName=Pong
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

 [Run]
 Filename: "{app}\Installers\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing .NET Framework 4.5.1"

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\vroy\Desktop\Debug\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\Pong"; Filename: "{app}\Pong.exe";
```

However when it tries to compile the .NET 4.5.1 installer file it shows the following error:

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

This makes no sense because the .NET 4.5.1 installer is not being used when I am compiling my Inno script.

Comment: Try to place your project files somewhere else than on the Desktop. Non-system folders are best for such things.

Comment: @RobeN That has worked, however now when I run the installer I get the error: "Unable to execute file "file location" CreateProcess faled; code 267. The directory name is invalid." I suspect this is because .NET 4.5.1 is already installed on my system. How would I make it so that my installer will not show a error message if .NET 4.5.1 is already installed?

Comment: No, that should not cause any issues. You would just see the info that .NET is installed and a question if you would like to uninstall or repair. Perhaps you point it wrongly in `[Run]` section or maybe you try to run it without Admin rights?

Comment: @RobeN I know it is displaying the error message because I already have .NET 4.5.1 installed. I checked Windows Event Viewer, and I saw the error: http://pastebin.com/buCZjBHM

Comment: Then you should use `Parameters: "/passive /norestart"` or you should write a `Check` function that would launch the .NET installation only if .NET not installed or Lower version installed.

Comment: @RobeN I am very new to Inno-Installer so I was wondering, where would I put these parameters in my script?

Comment: Before `StatusMsg` in the. E.g. `Filename: "{app}\Installers\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; Parameters: "/passive /norestart"; StatusMsg: "Installing .NET Framework 4.5.1"`